# Counting the number of images received in telegram

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot

There is a chat in telegram, I added a bot to it and now I want to count the number of images sent to the chat for the last day every day and put it in the table next to the desired date https://yadi.sk/i/1JEPn8s4ea0-uQ .
How can this be done?

Comment: Is `Webhook` set for your telegram bot or using `getUpdates`?

Comment: I use a Webhook

Comment: Create one method on your `Webhook` API to save incoming/outgoing data to database table and then group by date/as per requirement

Comment: I thought so, to log all messages and count by date and type of message. But after all, in a month oam will have a huge table with data on solschentyam, won't all this hang later?

Comment: You have to manage that things to get count :)